# Use np.where across column range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use np.where to create a new column based on conditions in three other columns.  In the below df, I want to make a new column 'score' that adds 1 to its value for every number in columns B,C,D that is 5 or less.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[5,7,9], 'C':[2,6,4], 'D':[6,7,8]})
df

    A   B   C   D
0   1   5   2   6
1   2   7   6   7
2   3   9   4   8
```

The hoped for result would look something like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   score
0   1   5   2   6     2
1   2   7   6   7     0
2   3   9   4   8     1
```

I can write an np.where condition for each column B,C,D individually, but don't know how to add them cumulatively; also the real data has hundreds of columns to query instead of just 3, so doing it by hand seems stupid, and I am sure there is a better way I am not thinking of!

Comment: your logic does not seem quite right; for columns B, C, D, none of them is less than or equal to 5 for the second row

Comment: you're right, score column should be 2,0,1.

Comment: ``df.assign(score = df.iloc[:, 1:].le(5).sum(1))`` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) with list of columns `cols` and `sum` for count `True`s:

```
cols = ['B','C','D']
df['score'] = df.le(5).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  score
0  1  5  2  6      2
1  2  7  6  7      0
2  3  9  4  8      1
```

If need all columns without first:

```
df['score'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].le(5).sum(axis=1)
```

If need all columns without `A` column:

```
df['score'] = df.drop('A', axis=1).le(5).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  In the example you provided, it looks like it applies to all 4 columns.  Is there a way to selectively apply .le to a subset of columns?

Comment: @suzanne - What means `selectively apply` ?

Comment: I mean I only want the score column to add a point for values in columns B,C,and D, not in A.   So if if I'm looking for values ge than 5, score should be 2,3,2, but if I'm looking for valued le 5, score should read 2,0,1 - i made a mistake in the original post.

Comment: @suzanne - No problem, only change `ge` to `le`, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** After OP changed the question. To get count of elements lesser than 5 in all columns mentioned in List C(where one could mention more elements in it too, as of now it has `B,C,D` as per shown samples).

```
c = ['B','C','D']
df['score'] = df[df[c].le(5)].count(1)
```

df will be as follows:

```
    A   B   C   D   score
0   1   5   2   6   2
1   2   7   6   7   0
2   3   9   4   8   1
```

---

---

With boolean masking you could try following.

```
m = df.le(5)
df['score'] = df[m].count(axis=1)
```

Output will be as follows for sample df:

```
    A   B   C   D   score
0   1   5   2   6   3
1   2   7   6   7   1
2   3   9   4   8   2
```